# Dealloc not getting called

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I am trying to debug why my override of dealloc is not getting called on one of my view controllers.

I have a view controller that is setup by storyboarding.  I have override all 3 init methods:

```
-(id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    NSLog(@"TestViewController init with coder");

    return [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
}

-(id) initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    NSLog(@"TestViewController init with nib name");

    return [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
}

- (id) init {
    NSLog(@"TestViewController init");

    return [super init];
}
```

When I navigate to the said view in my app I see that 'initWithCoder' is called as expected.  This is the only init method that I see called at all. It is called once when I navigate to my view.

However when I navigate away from my view controller dealloc does not get called.  viewDidDisappear does get called.  In view didDisappear I log the reference count:

```
-(void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"TestViewController Retain count is %ld", CFGetRetainCount((__bridge CFTypeRef) self));
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}
```

Reference count is 5.

I also log the reference count in viewDidLoad and it is 8.

So it jumps from 5 to 8, then back to 5.

I only see the init method called once.  I have no idea where to even start looking....

Comment: Note that it's not good enough to check the retain count, you also have to check all active autorelease pools, which you can do with `[NSAutoreleasePool showPools]`. You have a retain count of 5 but it might be in the autorelease pool 5 times. In general though, your retainCount will *always* be higher than zero. Once it hits zero there should never be any messages sent to it.

Comment: How are you navigating away from this controller?

Comment: @borrrden thanks! whentouseretaincount.com is a bit harsh, just started ios, but I get the point, I had no idea. The link you posted to SO answer on instruments is AWESOME.  Still not sure what the problem is, but I am sure to figure it out now. Will post when I solve to help anyone else, regardless instruments is the answer.

Comment: It is harsh, I agree.  However, the message got across right? ;)  The reason it is harsh is because people keep arguing for its use.  It's been well known for years not to use it but people still come up with excuses anyway.

Comment: DO NOT CLICK ON 'whentouseretaincount' above.  It is a virus that attempts to install software on your mac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an instance variable pointing to your viewController object?  If you still have a pointer it will not decrement the retain count even if the view is not on the screen.

The unusual retain counts are normal.  The only count that matters is 0.  If it is 0 it will be deallocated.  There is no guarantee that one pointer means there will be a retain count of 1.

Comment: Thanks!  Learning as I go, was really confused about the 'abnormal' ref counts numbers.  Using instruments to try and track down what is holding onto that ViewController.

Comment: Yup, had a strong reference to the view controller in another class.  Found it pretty quick when using instruments.